# What can the operator $T$ be?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve 3c from [this released exam](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F03_Final_Exam-A.Liu_.pdf):

> Determine all operators $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T^3 = T$ and $T^* = -T$. What can $T$ be?

From part b I have deduced that the eigenvalues must be imaginary. Using a similar argument to what I used in part b:

Consider any eigenvalue $\lambda$ for $T$ then:

$$Tx = \lambda x$$
and:
$$\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, -Ty \rangle$$
$$\langle T^3x, y \rangle = \langle x, -Ty \rangle$$
$$\langle \lambda^3x, y \rangle = \langle x, -\lambda y \rangle$$

Let $\lambda = ib$ and we see:

$$ \lambda^3 = -\overline{\lambda}$$
$$ (ib)^3 = ib$$
$$ -ib = ib$$
$$ b = 0$$

So the eigenvalues must be all zero then. I do not know how to make any further deductions, any further guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T^3 = T$ implies that [T is diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74810/why-is-the-condition-enough-for-a-matrix-to-be-diagonalizable).

Hence T is diagonalizable and 0 is its only eigenvalue. What can you conclude ?

Comment: This would imply that $T = P^{-1}DP$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. But the eigenvalues as I have shown must be $0$ so $D = 0$ hence $T = P^{-1}0P = 0$ so $T = 0$. Thanks.